# ¿Cómo puedo separar una cadena de texto en dos partes con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero separar un string en dos partes por un guión y cada parte que sea guardada en una variable distinta

```
var dato= "hola a todos-cómo están";

var dato1="hola a todos";
var dato2="cómo están";
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dato= "hola a todos-cómo están";
var dato1=dato.split('-');
var a=dato1[0]
var b =dato1[1]
```

Lo que hace split es que crear un arreglo desde un separador que le indicas en este caso será el -

Answer (score 2):

Se hace con el método `split` del *String*. Se declara un array, en este ejemplo lo llamaremos `datos`. Los arrays tienen la posición comenzada en *cero (0)* en vez de *uno (1)*, entonces, se accede de la siguiente manera.

Para el primer valor:

```
datos[0] // El equivalente de dato1
```

Para el segundo valor:

```
datos[1] // El equivalente de dato2
```

Para separarlo con el guión se hace `dato.split("-")`, luego para asignar el array a la variable se hace ***`var datos =`***`dato.split("-")`.

Código completo:

```js
var dato = "hola a todos-cómo están"
var datos = dato.split("-")
console.log( datos[0] )
console.log( datos[1] )
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay muchas formas de separar un string en dos partes, quizás la más simple es usar `split` y otra complicada para los que aún no se familiarizan con esta es el usar expresiones regulares.

1. Usar `split`

```js
var dato= "hola a todos-cómo están";

console.info(dato.split('-'));
```

`split` devuelve un Array donde cada elemento corresponde a una parte

2. Usar expresiones regulares y `exec`

```js
var dato= "hola a todos-cómo están";
var re = new RegExp ("(^.*?)-(.*)$");
console.info(re.exec(dato))
```

`exec` devuelve un `Array` donde el primer element es la cadena que coincide con la expresión y los elementos siguientes corresponden a cada grupo de captura.

Si estas familiarizado con el manejo de Arrays el asignar cada parte resultaría trivial y posiblemente hasta innecesario.

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp